# PHP Output xml data

Tags: php, html, xml, xml-parsing

I make an appearance timetable that takes data from a database. But in my case, I take the data directly to the file data *.xml

Or in other words I do the scheduling for periodic data collection.
But this resulted in data that I show is not dynamic. because it can only read the file *. xml it. I want to create a function in php and xml data outpunya be like this :

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "user";
$dbpass = "pass";
$dbname = "my_epg";
mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname);

include "Encoding.php";

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta");
$DataTanggal = strip_tags(date("l, jS, F Y"));

sql = "select distinct(channel_name) FROM epg";
$q   = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$xml = "<timetable start='00:00' end='24:00' title='".$DataTanggal."'>";

while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
       $CN = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($r['channel_name']));
           $xml .= "<location name='".$CN."'>"; 


        $sql2 = "select * FROM epg where channel_name='".$CN."'";
        $q2  = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());

while($r2 = mysql_fetch_array($q2)){
    $Mulai      = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(date('H:i', strtotime($r2['waktu_mulai']))));
    $Selesai    = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(date('H:i', strtotime($r2['waktu_akhir']))));
    $Title      = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($r2['judul']));
    $Desk       = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($r2['sinopsis']));

      $Encoding1 = Encoding::fixUTF8($TitleValid);
      $Encoding2 = Encoding::fixUTF8($DeskValid);

    $xml .= "<event start='".$MulaiValid."' end='".$SelesaiValid."'>";
    $xml .= "<title>".$Encoding1."</title>";
    $xml .= "<description>".$Encoding2."</description>";
    $xml .= "</event>"; 
}

$xml .= "</location>";
}



$xml .= "</timetable>";
echo $xml;
?>
```

The results of this successful process php file and output the same as the *.xml accessed. Now the problem I use timetable.class.php to process this data.

```
public function createTimetable($url) {

    //Load xml file
    $xml = @simplexml_load_file($url, NULL, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

    if(!$xml) {
        echo 'Error: there is an error in your XML file: <a href="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a>';
        return;
    }

    if (strpos($url, 'http://') === 0 || strpos($url, 'https://') === 0 || strpos($url, 'ftp://') === 0) {
        echo 'Error: the path to your xml file may not start with "http://"';
        return;
    }

    //Set the settings
    $this->setSettings($xml, $url);

    $this->writeHTML($xml);

    echo $this->mbencoding($this->output);
    return;

}
```

But this function can only be used to read data from an existing file (*.xml). Not dynamic php process.

My question: How do I create a process on this class.php with a get or post the data to make it dynamic so I can access the link address that I have made ​​the process of type xml echo?

Comment: http://php.net/wrappers.data.php - and make that function allow to accept `data://` URIs, too, next to http(s)/ftp. - Also there is [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://php.net/simplexml_load_string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your Dinamic PHP file, you can save a file as the generated XML with this:

```
 $file = fopen("generated.xml","w");

 fwrite($file, $xml);

 fclose($file);
```

Then, in the function createTimetable load the saved XML file.